# UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier issue with Async Image Loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uicollectionview

So problem is simple. I want to make an Instagram like screen where user can infinitely view the images while scrolling up from bottom.

I've managed to download next page's image when user reaches at bottom.
I'm using `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` in my `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, and I'm downloading images asynchronously using  [AsyncImageView Library](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView).

Problem is - While scrolling up/down, the images in cell getting on/off. Means at first cell displays the old image and then displays the new one after asynchronously downloading. I want a smooth effect like Instagram where new cells appended at bottom as blank cell and then images load.

Here is my code.

First in `viewWillAppear`

```
[self.photosCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:kPhotoCell bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCollectionViewCellId];
```

And then

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)paramCollView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [paramCollView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellectionViewCellId forIndexPath:indexPath];
    PhotoBO *singlePhoto = [self.photosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [((AsyncImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:10]) setImageURL:[PhotoBL getPhotoURL:singlePhoto]];
    return cell;
}
```

To sum up all, please [watch this video of my app](http://1drv.ms/1IFWL6q) running in simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up with following solution

- Removed the `AsyncImageView` library from my code.
- Introduced [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for network calls and async image downloading.
- In `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, set the cell image as `nil` before setting new image
- Used following method of `UIImageView+AFNetworking` to download the image in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

`-(void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage;`

And everything is fine now. I have achieved the smooth scrolling effect and issue of images on/off has also solved.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

1. Only download image in NSDefaultRunLoopMode,because when you scroll the collection view,the runloop mode will be set in UITrackingRunLoopMode.
2. Cache your downloaded image.
3. Clean the cell when you reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) is much better library to get what you want. It has both downloading and caching and works great. Works out of the box, easily integrated.

Alternatively you may use [FastImageCache](https://github.com/path/FastImageCache) + AFNetworking to get the best performance and FPS of your UI. This will need a bit more code, but the result is impressive. You really should look at it.

Comment: I shall definitely try this. Previously I had been using `AsyncImageView` in many projects, but here it couldn't solve my problem. I have heard about `SDWebImage` before but did never get a chance to try this.